# New to android and need an explanation about @+id/edit_message

Tags: android

`<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"`
`android:layout_weight="1"`
`android:layout_width="0dp"`
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
`android:hint="@string/edit_message" />`

what is the purpose of @+id/edit_message? I am searching for it yet I haven't found a clear explanations.

Comment: "I am searching for it" -- where? "yet I haven't found a clear explanations" -- hard to believe. I recommend you find a few tutorials, or you will very quickly be very frustrated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because **it shows no effort in googling**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means you are creating a reference for the `EditText` so that it can be used in another `View`, layout file, or in your Java code.

To me, it is very much like declaring a variable in your code.

```
String ggjon = "New to android and need an explanation";
```

The difference between using @+id/edit_message and @id/edit_message is declaration vs. referencing an already declared View.

Answer (score 0):

You define id for your TextEdit. Thanks to that You can access it via Java code:

```
 EditText myedit = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```